# The relational model’s conceptual simplicity was bought at the expense of computer overhead - meaning of bought?

Tags: meaning

> In 1970, Codd’s work was considered ingenious but impractical. The relational model’s conceptual simplicity was **bought** at the expense of computer overhead; computers at that time lacked the power to implement the relational model. Fortunately, computer power grew exponentially, as did operating system efficiency. Better yet, the cost of computers diminished rapidly as their power grew.

I don't quite understand what **bought** means in the second sentence.

Comment: Intuitively, I think it alludes to the most basic sense of "buy", which is easy to be overlooked because "buy" these days is almost always about money. But the essence of "buy" is gaining something at the cost of some other things.

Comment: @DamkerngT. That's right - post it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intuitively, I think it alludes to the most basic sense of "buy", which is usually overlooked because "buy" these days is almost always about money. But the essence of "buy" is gaining something at the cost of some other things.

I looked it up in a dictionary and found a definition similar to that idea,

> **[buy](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/buy)**
>   3. [transitive] to get something that you want or need, usually by losing something else that is important
>   **buy something with something:** *attempts to buy peace with land*
>   **buy something at the expense/cost of something:** *Increased profits would be bought at the expense of paying less attention to quality.*

So, you can understand your sentence,

> The relational model's conceptual simplicity was bought at the expense of computer overhead; ...

like this: in order to buy the simplicity (of the model), we had to buy it with computer overhead. That is, the computer would have to do more work (thus the term "overhead") so that we would be able to have such simplicity of the relational model.